# Java Thread.Join() method not waiting for thread to finish

Tags: java, multithreading

I have this section of code: CustomerClient is basically a class that extends Thread.
I am trying to spawn multiple threads but only one at a time. However Im getting an illegal thread state exception. What am I doing wrong?

```
CustomerClient cusClient = new CustomerClient("B", server_IP_1,
            server_Port_1, server_IP_2, server_Port_2);

    while (true) {
        System.out.println("new thread A");
        cusClient.start();
        cusClient.join();
    }
```

Comment: please share the complete exception

Comment: You aren't creating new threads at all (except once). You're repeatedly calling `start()` on an existing Thread. Unrelated suggestion: You almost never should have a class extend Thread but rather implement Runnable. In this situation you would create a new Runnable, put it into a new Thread and start that thread in the while loop.

Comment: @Gray: he states that the CustomerClient extends Thread at the beginning of his question.

Comment: do you add synchronized with your business logic??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A thread can be started only once. So need to initialize the thread object everytime in the loop.

```
while (true) {
    CustomerClient cusClient = new CustomerClient("B", server_IP_1,
        server_Port_1, server_IP_2, server_Port_2);
    System.out.println("new thread A");
    cusClient.start();
    cusClient.join();
}
```

Comment: @Gray Starting the same thread in an infinite loop will give the exception

Comment: Still, this is weird. Calling `start()` then `join()` in a serial form like this is essentially the same as not using any threads at all.

Comment: @JasonC: Yep, this smells like a classic [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).